# Combine 2 files based on the date using awk or sed

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I have 2 files , the format is as follow,

File1 's contents,

```
02-01-12 28.46
02-02-12 27.15
02-03-12 47.54
02-04-12 27.36
02-05-12 47.57
02-06-12 27.01
02-07-12 27.41
02-08-12 27.27
02-09-12 27.39
```

File2 's contents,

```
02-01-12 11.46
02-02-12 12.15
02-03-12 14.54
02-04-12 15.36
02-05-12 17.57
02-06-12 17.01
02-07-12 17.41
02-08-12 21.27
02-09-12 17.39
```

I want to combine them into 1 file based on the date as below,

```
02-01-12 28.46 11.46
02-02-12 27.15 12.15
02-03-12 47.54 14.54
....................
....................
....................
```

Please help !! Thanks in advance..

Comment: is it fixed that each file has one and only one entry of time per date?

Comment: sorry , just fixed the format of my question

Answer (score 4):

what you want is `join`:

*from the man page*:

> join - join lines of two files on a common field

try:

```
$ join file1 file2
```

Comment: @Karl Nordström, the file ordering is fine. file2 comes *second* on OP's example. `02-01-12 28.46 11.46` breaks down to 1. `02-01-12` - the common part, 2. `28.46` - part from file1, 3. `11.46` - part from file2.

Answer (score 0):

Full real working example using `paste` :

```
paste FILE1 <(cut -d " " -f2 FILE2)
```

See :

```
man 1 paste
```

Answer (score 0):

Using just sed:

```
/bin/sed -n '
p
R f2
' f1 |
/bin/sed 'N;s/\n[^ ]*//;'
```